# "modified: Gemfile.lock", Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, git-branch

When I '`git status`' on my sub branch, I frequently see "**modified:   Gemfile.lock**", BUT I have never touch this file, why git always tell me it is modified??

I am developing Rails 3 application under Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is because you ran

```
bundle install
```

it will change the Gemfile.lock to tell exactly what versions of each gem your project is using so that when something breaks, you can trace back what versions of gem you were using earlier.

Comment: And more to the point so that if you run 'bundle install' on another machine, it installs the very same versions that were present on your dev machine.

Answer (score 3):

I see the same thing when developing on Mac OS and Ubuntu.
When I pull the code to Ubuntu machine that has Gemfile.lock created on Mac machine, and after running rails server I get Gemfile.lock modified:

```
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index 7fcc61b..5f06101 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -113,7 +113,7 @@ GEM
     faraday (0.5.3)
       addressable (~> 2.2.2)
       multipart-post (~> 1.0.1)
-      rack (>= 1.1.0, < 2)
+      rack (< 2, >= 1.1.0)
     formtastic (1.2.3)
       actionpack (>= 2.3.7)
       activesupport (>= 2.3.7)
@@ -126,9 +126,9 @@ GEM
       haml (~> 3.0)
       railties (~> 3.0)
     heroku (1.13.7)
-      json_pure (>= 1.2.0, < 1.5.0)
+      json_pure (< 1.5.0, >= 1.2.0)
       launchy (~> 0.3.2)
-      rest-client (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7.0)
+      rest-client (< 1.7.0, >= 1.4.0)
     heroku_san (1.0.7)
       heroku
     hpricot (0.8.3)
```

Looks like not essential changes, just reordered version constraints. But quite annoying.
I usually

```
git checkout -- Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Without running `bundle` I have changes in the Gemfile.lock (for me it's only `json_pure` `(>= 1.2.0, < 1.5.0)` vs `(< 1.5.0, >= 1.2.0)`). Some time ago I've read a blog post about it, but ignored it then. Now that I have the same issue I cannot seem to find it :/

Comment: It was a Bundler issue. It has been fixed in version 1.0.11 (after installing this version I no longer have this issue).

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue with Bundler version 1.1.5.

Comment: Bundler version 1.7.6 here and still have the same problem